# I cannot rename column 'Attachment' in List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, attachments

I was able to rename the attachments column before easily. Just right click on column name and choose rename.

But this button is now gone. I tried many times but I cannot find this option now. I can rename another column, just choose edit button and change name.

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you want to rename the attachment column?

Comment: I want to specific item for attached when someone key in share point

Comment: Hi @TheGifts, does my answer below helped you to rename attachments column via browser/SharePoint UI? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to rename attachments column from browser/SharePoint UI:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on settings (gear) icon from top right corner and select **List settings** option
3. Scroll down to **Columns** section on list settings page and click on any column name (For example "Title").
4. Then replace "Title" in the URL with "Attachments" after `&Field=` in below format and press Enter to open column settings for attachments column:

   ```
   https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/wlive/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B753C3ED6-1F4F-499E-910D-D67375F3239A%7D&Field=Attachments
   ```

   [image]
5. Change column name and click **OK** button at the bottom of column settings page to save the column settings.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to do like you but cannot find 4.Then replace "Title" in the URL with "Attachments" after &Field= in below format and press Enter to open column settings for attachments column: , I can change any column but cannot column ' Attachment

Comment: Are you able to open the attachments column settings as shown in first image?

Comment: I know why I didn't see attachment column, I click to list setting and scroll down to column and found all column but didn't see attachment also I setting enable attachment already. -_- How I can do. Last month I can rename attachment by click on web display column attachment and choose rename very easy.

Comment: This column is not visible under "Columns" section automatically. You have to Open column setting for another column, then change URL which will point to attachments column, enter URL and you will be taken to column settings page of Attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use PowerShell to rename the "Attachment" column name.

```
Function Rename-ListColumn()
{
  param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ColumnName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String[]] $NewName
    )
 
    Try {
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
         
        #Get the List
        $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $Ctx.Load($List)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Get the column to rename
        $Field = $List.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($ColumnName)
        $Field.Title = $NewName
        $Field.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
             
        Write-Host "Column Name Changed successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
 
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Renaming Column!" $_.Exception.Message
    } 
}
 
#Parameters
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
$ListName="Projects"
$ColumnName="Titles"
$NewName="Project Title"
 
#Call the function to rename column
Rename-ListColumn -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName -ColumnName $ColumnName -NewName $New
```

[image]

Output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , I never use Powershell

Comment: Only PowerShell could rename this column name.

Comment: We can rename column from browser/UI as well as shown in my answer below.